# Sass logic not being applied if contained in mixin, but applied from function

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, sass, web-compiler

I have two sets of Sass logic that should do the same thing, but the results are distinctly different.

Can anyone explain to me why the conditional logic contained within the mixin was not applied to the results, but the same logic abstracted into a function was?

Both versions were invoked with:

```
@include maximizable-dialog($max-width: 650px);
```

The default values are:

```
$default-height: 550px;
$default-width:  960px;
```

**Version 1: Mixin**

```
@mixin maximizable-dialog($min-width: $default-width, $min-height: $default-height, $max-width: none, $max-height: none) {

    // if the minimum is too large, revert to defaults
    @if ($min-width > $default-width) {
        $min-width: $default-width;
    }

    // reduce the minimum if it is larger than the maximum
    @if not ($max-width == none) {
        @if $max-width < $default-width {
            @if ($max-width < $min-width) {
                $min-width: $max-width;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the minimum is too large, revert to defaults
    @if ($min-height > $default-height) {
        $min-height: $default-height;
    }

    // reduce the minimum if it is larger than the maximum
    @if not ($max-height == none) {
        @if ($max-height < $default-height) {
            @if ($max-height < $min-height) {
                $min-height: $max-height;
            }
        }
    }

    min-height: $min-height;
    max-height: $max-height;
    min-width: $min-width;
    max-width: $max-width;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
min-height: 550px;
max-height: none;
min-width: 960px; // larger than expected
max-width: 650px;
```

**Version 2: Mixin & Function**

```
@function maximizable-dialog-min-value($min, $max, $default) {
    // if the minimum is too large, revert to defaults
    @if ($min > $default) {
        $min: $default;
    }

    // reduce the minimum if it is larger than the maximum
    @if not ($max == none) {
        @if ($max < $default) {
            @if ($max < $min) {
                $min: $max;
            }
        }
    }

    @return $min;
}

@mixin maximizable-dialog($min-width: $default-width, $min-height: $default-height, $max-width: none, $max-height: none) {
    min-height: maximizable-dialog-min-value($min-height, $max-height, $default-height);
    max-height: $max-height;
    min-width: maximizable-dialog-min-value($min-width, $max-width, $default-width);
    max-width: $max-width;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
min-height: 550px;
max-height: none;
min-width: 650px; // exactly what's expected
max-width: 650px;
```

Comment: How do you compile sass? I got the same outputs for these two code blocks on sassmeister. https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3973da19d5a30af32d38269d4a4e6a58 and https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/33e4c9e60685d2dfc0a2389fe5470efa

Comment: I use the BuildWebCompiler NuGet package in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @3rdthemagical I find it very interesting that you had the same outputs for both. That's what I would have expected to see in my build. While I am happier with the second version of the code, I also want to understand the discrepancy. There's a valuable learning opportunity in there somewhere.